# Is it possible to assign the same BitmapDrawable to multiple Objects?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I create a BitmapDrawable that I later assign to several Objects in a function like this (not exactly like this but its stripped down for testing purposes):

```
Drawable CreateBitmap(int col)
{   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawColor(col);
    return new BitmapDrawable(b);
}
```

And this works and creates me a BitmapDrawable with the size 50 x 50 that I keep in memory. I then assign this BitmapDrawable to various buttons, checkboxes, whatever comes up and needs a certain color.

the problem I have is that the BitmapDrawables are somehow getting truncated. It appears that if I assign it to a button with the height of 80 and then a button with the height of 160, the first is filled nicely and the latter is only filled by half. It appears the BitmapDrawable gets set to the first usage of it and all subsequent assignments are restricted by it. Sometimes it happens immediately sometimes it only happens when I switch to another tab and return back to the previous one.

I thought the BitmapDrawable would remain at 50x50 in memory and the object its assigned to is either getting its own version with an apropriate size (or makes a resized copy when rendering) and not that it somehow changes the BitmapDrawable itself. I admit, I am not sure how all of this works in depth and I would appreciate any advice on what I am doing wrong and if I do have to create individual BitmapDrawables for each object I assign them to or if I can do something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BitmapDrawable is a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) object, containing methods such as [setState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setState%28int%5B%5D%29) that are pretty specific to an *instance* of the object. So, no, I don't think a BitmapDrawable can be easily shared. (You *might* be able to reuse them successfully, much as ListView caches the Views for list members; but asking a BitmapDrawable to live in two or more places at the same time seems like it's asking too much of it.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will then use individual Bitmaps for the objects. But I will use the same ones for the ListViews, as I didn't experience any problems with that, and that should be fine, right ?

Comment: @HardCoder: I'm not sure what your question means. As long as the BitmapDrawable only appears in one view at a time, though, it should be fine. However, that includes individual ListView items. If you want to use the same BitmapDrawable on two different ListView items, you need to make sure that they're never both visible at the same time.

Comment: Well so far, I use them in different Listviews and in different items and had no Problem so far with that. But I will make different btimapdrawables for the list. I do have some cases where they are visible for different items at the same time but never had any problems with that (not even with 2 lists tbh). Should I change that to be on the safe side?

Comment: @HardCoder: That is certainly what I would suggest.

Comment: By the way, from a quick look at the source for BitmapDrawable, it looks as if you *can* assign the same underlying Bitmap to multiple BitmapDrawables. (I'd been guessing that that was true, but I wasn't sure enough to suggest it until now.) If you're worried about conserving memory, sharing the Bitmaps would probably take care of most of the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at BitmapDrawable.mutate(). It will create a copy of the drawables constant state, but still share the undelying bitmap between drawables.

```
ImageView imgView1 = findByViewId(R.id.my_image_view_1);
ImageView imgView2 = findByViewId(R.id.my_image_view_2);

BitmapDrawable image = new BitmapDrawable("/path/to/my/bitmap");

imgView1.setImageDrawable(image);
imgView2.setImageDrawable(image.mutate());
```

That should give you 2 distinct states, without copying the bitmap.

There's a nice article about it here:
http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/